# How do I save data in two tables CakePHP

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I have a form with two input fields and i would like to save the data from one field inside one table and the other one inside the second table. My main table is multimedia, the second is descriptions.

**I use this to save one file to the main table:**

```
$multimedia->set('original_file', $original_filename);
```

I'm using *CakePHP* 3

**Edit**

My add function:

```
   public function add()
{
    $multimedia = $this->Multimedia->newEntity();
    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        $multimedia = $this->Multimedia->patchEntity($multimedia, $this->request->data);


        $hi = $this->data['Descriptions']['title'];
        $bye = $this->data['Descriptions']['description'];

          // Saving the file
        $file = $_FILES['url'];
        //$path = "webroot\\files\\" .$_FILES['url']['name']; //server
        //Web File
        $path = WWW_ROOT."files" .$_FILES['url']['name'];  //Windows
        $success = move_uploaded_file($_FILES['url']['tmp_name'], $path);
        // Original File
        $path = WWW_ROOT."files" .$_FILES['original_file']['name'];  //Windows
        $success = move_uploaded_file($_FILES['original_file']['tmp_name'], $path);

        $filename = $_FILES['url']['name'];
        $original_filename = $_FILES['original_file']['name'];

        $created = $_SESSION['Auth']['User']['id'];

        $type = mime_content_type($path);

        $multimedia->set('mime_type', $type);
        $multimedia->set('url', $filename);
        $multimedia->set('original_file', $original_filename);
        $multimedia->set('created_by', $created);

        echo $multimedia;
        echo "<br>";
        echo $filename;
        echo "<br>";
        echo $hi;
        exit();

        if ($this->Multimedia->save($multimedia)) {
            $this->Flash->success('The multimedia has been saved.');
            return $this->redirect(['action' => 'index']);
        } else {
            $this->Flash->error('The multimedia could not be saved. Please, try again.');
        }
    }
    $languages = $this->Multimedia->Languages->find('list', ['limit' => 200]);
    $categories = $this->Multimedia->Categories->find('list', ['limit' => 200]);
    $users = $this->Multimedia->Users->find('list', ['limit' => 200]);
    $descriptions = $this->Multimedia->Descriptions->find('list', ['limit' => 200]);
    $this->set(compact('multimedia', 'languages', 'categories', 'users', 'descriptions'));
    $this->set('_serialize', ['multimedia']);
}
```

Comment: you'll need to do it in 2 steps, can't you just add this `$descriptions->set('second_field', $data_from_second_field);` ?

Comment: when i try to print what $descriptions it give me an error, post updated